# Running iPad app from Xamarin Studio fails

Tags: ios, ipad, xamarin.ios, runtime, xamarin-studio

I am trying to run an iOS iPad app from Xamarin Studio to an iPad that I have connected.

The project builds but when its deployed to the device and the iPad attempts to load it, I get the alert message **"Trial. Trial executable has expired (24 hours limit)"**. I have been deploying to iPad's to test my project for a couple of weeks now so I can't see why this error is occuring.

**How can I run to a device successfully from Xamarin Studio?**

I have tried unplugging/reconnecting the device. Closing/restarting Xamarin Studio. Even trie restarting my Mac and loading the projects up from scratch. No luck.

I am trying to build/run in **Release**.

**Debug** doesn't build it says **"The specified provisioning profile "xxxxxxx" could not be found"**.

And **Ad-Hoc** doesn't build it says **"Project bundle ID 'xxxx' does not match specified provisioning profile 'xxxx'"**

**Edit**: Version details

Xamarin Studio
Version 4.0.12 (build 3)
Installation UUID: xxxx
Runtime:
    Mono 3.2.0 ((no/7c7fcc7)
    GTK 2.24.20
    GTK# (2.12.0.0)
    Package version: 302000000

**Edit:** Xamarin.iOS Version Details:

Xamarin.iOS. Version: 6.4.5.0 (trial Edition), Hash: 1336a36, Branch: , Build Date: 2013-10-09 11:14:45-0400

Comment: Can you show the version information from Xamarin Studio (About -> Show Details)?

Comment: @RolfBjarneKvinge Hi, i've added the version details to the question

Comment: Please add all the version information, not just for Xamarin Studio.

Comment: can I ask why you need all that? some of it looks sensitive so im reluctant to put it all on here

Comment: The only thing that can be traced back to you is the Installation UUID (which you've already removed). All the other hashes are related to versions of the products. In particular I'm interested in which version and edition of Xamarin.iOS you have.

Comment: When I build to the simulator now I get the alert: "Trial. Trial Executable has expired (24 hours limit)"

Comment: @RolfBjarneKvinge I have added more details to the question. It says I am still in trial.. could that cause it. I don't think the trial is over yet. We have the full ios licence, how do I upgrade my current version from trial to the full ios dev licence?

Comment: Can you try to clean & rebuild your project? Also check that the (system) date on the device and machine are correct.

Comment: Clean All. Then a Rebuild all. Then run and... it runs! Sounds so obvious now, thank you. If you set that as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can you try to clean & rebuild your project? Also check that the (system) date on the device and machine are correct.

Comment: The clock! Good call.